# how can i read and write to mips cp0 registers from mips16 ISA

Tags: gcc, assembly, mips32

I have been given the task of reducing the code size for our project which is based on mips32r2 ISA, so my first goal is to re-compile my project into mips16 ISA, but the files which uses gcc "asm" directive to read and write mips cp0 register are not being compiled.
i want know how to read and write to mips cp0 register in mips16 ISA

Comment: Does MIPS16 allow efficient call/return to a MIPS32 function, the way ARM Thumb interworking does?  If so, you could put your code that modifies `cp0` into MIPS32 functions, and only compile everything else as MIPS16.  (There are probably gcc function attributes for this, or put them in a separate compilation unit.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, I Have actually found a solution to the issue by using GCC attribute directive, the functions which are reading and writing to cp0 register are now compiled with __attribute__((nomips16)).thanks anyway :)